# ¿Cómo podría eliminar los bordes del iframe y que el iframe ocupara toda la pestaña?

Tags: html, css

He creado un iframe y me gustaría que ocupara toda la pantalla y que se le quitara los bordes. He intentado el siguiente código de css y ha pasado algo raro.

1. No se han quitado.
2. Se ha aplicado como un `margin-bottom` raro.

Dejo mis códigos y me decís qué podría hacer. Cabe destacar que al código le faltan partes porque estaba probando.

HTML CODE + CSS:

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body{
        color:white;
    }

     iframe{
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%
          border:none;

     }
     
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    

    <div class="root">
    <iframe src="on_load/index.html" title="Perfumeria">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un atributo en el iframe se declara el borde:

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Y también los estilos de las dimensiones:

```
<iframe src="" height="100vh" width="100%" >
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución de @NarcisoAifuz es buena, pero podría presentar algún problema en dispositivos móviles:

[image: Problema 100vh en móviles]

100 unidades de View Height pueden calcularse contando la barra de dirección, con lo que parte del contenido quedará oculto. Creo que es más portable una solución clásica con posición absoluta como esta:

```html
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right:0">
  <iframe src="./iframe.html" frameborder=0 style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
</div>
```